# Current location

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Do you know how to get current location? I mean not for file, but from where it was called. For e.g.:

*c:\Users\Joe>e:\tmp\tmp.bat*

Should return `c:\Users\Joe`, not `e:\tmp\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo %~dp0
```

this should return directory of the bat.

```
echo %cd%
```

this should return current directory.

Comment: No, if the %~dp0 is in the tmp.bat, it will return ` E:\tmp\ `, when run from e:\tmp\tmp.bat

Comment: @Jubjub, I know how DPO works, npocmaka edited his answer after I had posted my comment.  If you saw his original post you would understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW looks like %cd% returns always c:\windows if called from total cmd. :? I will have to go around with parameters.

Comment: @user2868288, %CD% depends on how the script is invoked. If you're using a shortcut or something, it will probably default to somewhere in the %WINDIR% directory, but if you invoke it in some other way (command line, script, some other program), it will inherit the CWD from the invoking program.